# Getting two result sets from SQL Server query gives two different outputs

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I created a stored procedure which works fine on my local sql server database but the same procedure not working on Live Server of bigrocks. Actually i getting data from two tables in two different queries , in live environment the data from first query is fetch only.

Please suggest how to solve this.

```
CRAETE procedure [dbo].[usp_RegisterTable_GetAllUserName]
as
begin

select [User_Id],UserName from RegisterTable where Status='Active' 
select [User_Id],UserName from DistributerTable where Status='Active'
end
```

Thanks..

Comment: I hate to ask, but given your comments below, are you sure the live server's data has something in [DistributerTable] with an active status?

Comment: @jlee-tessik I have data in distributer table and it wworks fine when i run on local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two different procedures for these queries and merge the result sets in your application code.I give you a example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FromRgisterTable
AS
BEGIN
select [User_Id],UserName from RegisterTable where Status='Active'
END

CREATE PROCEDURE FromDistributerTable
AS
BEGIN
select [User_Id],UserName from DistributerTable where Status='Active'
END
```

In your application code in c# like

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("FromFirstProcedure", Connect());
            sqlda1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlda1.Fill(dt1);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("FromSecondProcedure", Connect());
            sqlda2.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlda2.Fill(dt2);
            dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

I think it should done your work.

Comment: @MohdAdeeb you can mark this as answer if your work has done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select [User_Id],UserName 
from RegisterTable 
where Status='Active' 

UNION ALL

select [User_Id],UserName 
from DistributerTable 
where Status='Active'
```

Or are you looking for two different resultsets?

Comment: Ya i tried this but only first query executes the second query not executes in both situations

Comment: @MohdAdeeb first test the procedure in database by executing query `exec usp_RegisterTable_GetAllUserName`

Comment: @MohdWaseem i test it it works fine in database but in my code it only shows data from first query